# Mixing Android External JAR and JNI gone wild

Tags: android, jar, java-native-interface, android-ndk

A short history. please bear with me :)

I have an Android project that uses JNI which works very good.

I've decided to create out of the source of this jni project an external jar (for distribution)

In order to create this jar I've taken the advice of others and created a new Java project that holds the few jni classes I need to store in the jar. I've exported this java project to a jar (not as a runnable jar)

I've created a new Android Project in which I try to use the jar file in question.

After I've played with this new android project I came to realize that the .so file which should accompany the jni classes can't reside inside the jar file itself (Eclipse complained about it..) So I've created a lib directory inside the new Android Project which holds the .so file.

When I run this new Android project I can't work with any of the classes which has native methods, And I can only work with those classes which are pure java implementation.

I keep getting "ExceptionInInitializerError" when trying to create an instance of one of jni based objects.

Update:
It seems that the error comes from trying to load the jni library in line

```
System.loadLibrary("lib-jni");
```

Here is the logcat:

```
> ERROR/SightEngine(2479): About to load the lib-jni.so
ERROR/SightExample(2479): WARNING: Could not init SightEngine java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eyesight.android.example/eyesight.android.example.SightExample}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479):     at android.util.Log.println(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479):     at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:208)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479):     at eyesight.android.example.SightExample.onCreate(SightExample.java:28)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479):     ... 11 more
ERROR/dalvikvm(2479): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

A few pointers:

- I can see the .so file inside the .apk file.
- I've tried defining the external jar file in the JNI Android.mk but nothing exciting happened. here are the lines I used (it compiled without a problem..)

  LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libtestjar:lib/testJar.jar
  include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
- I'm able to work with regular java classes that exist only in jar file. (I know I'm repeating myself.. :) ) which means I've correctly defined this jar in the project.

  - The java project that holds the jni based classes has a reference to the android.jar (sdk level 7)

Does anyone has any suggestions has to how this task can be accomplished? I feel like I'm almost there...

Thank you for your time and effort :)

Itamar

Comment: logcat added. Also the current version of the Android.mk file that produced the .so file is with the PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIB. I'm not sure if this is even necessary because I'm not compiling the .so against an external jar, but compiling only the Java side of the jni to a jar. makes sense?

Comment: How does your .so build? The native library should be built for ARM (by ndk)

Comment: The .so is built for arm. As I mentioned, I know that this specific ndk project is fine because I use it in a regular Android project which doesn't try to put its Java source in a jar. I did change the package name when I created the Java project from which I exported the jar, so I've updated the jni code to comply with the new package name. If a namespace issue was the thing I think I would've seen UnsatisfiedLinkError rather than the exception I'm getting.

Answer (score 1):

In the android project, did you put your .so files under lib/armeabi ?

by the way, i have the same setup as you (java project that builds a jar and an android project that uses the jar).

I managed to package the .so files in the jar ...  here's what I did:

-when building the library JAR, I zip the .so files into a file (say armeabi.zip) and put it inside an 'assets' folder in the jar.

-when building the android project, the armeabi.zip will be in the 'assets' folder inside your apk.

-at runtime (first start) I extract the contents of armeabi.zip from the assets into "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName().

-finally load the extracted .so libs using System.load(/data/data//libfilename.so)

hope this helps.

Fadi

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an error log call is missing a message.

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479): at android.util.Log.println(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479): at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:208)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2479): at eyesight.android.example.SightExample.onCreate(SightExample.java:28)
```

Comment: 10x, Indeed there was a Log.e attempt when catching the exception that had null in it. however this is not the issue and still I get ExceptionInInitializerError.